# how to get emp id for any change values happend after first record

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have emp table
it contains many colmuns and an employee can have many rows beside on the 
changed happend to his/her records . it hasnt primary key because emp id can 
 repeated beside on employee values .
there's a column `"health"` ,it decribes the health and `with  values(heart,skin,null) etc..` 
 and `modification_date` for each change of values in a health column
let's say employee number 1 has a heart problem as a first record registed in a health column
then the employee got well then added a second row and column health=null , 
after sometimes the employee got sick to a nother disease 'skin'

how to get employee number if his/her column(health) 
has been change to any values of health if values become null or other values ?

any help please ?

```
select empid, health_status from
(
    select e.emp_id empid, e.health health_status,
           count(e.health) over (partition by e.emp_id order by e.modification_date asc) sick_count
    from emp e
)
where sick_count > 1
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are after. An employee can get sick and get well again. So what do you want to know? Whether an employee ever got sick? Whether an employee is sick now? How many sicknesses an employee has or had? Something else?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statement for your table; the `INSERT` statements for some sample data; the expected output for that sample data; and an explanation of why that output is expected.

Answer (score 2):

Seems you need counting `NULL`s and `NOT-NULL`s. [`NVL2()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/NVL2.html#GUID-414D6E81-9627-4163-8AC2-BD24E57742AE) function would suit well in order to compute this such as

```sql
SELECT e.emp_id, e.health,
       SUM(NVL2(health,1,0)) OVER (PARTITION BY e.emp_id) AS "Sick",
       SUM(NVL2(health,0,1)) OVER (PARTITION BY e.emp_id) AS "Got well"       
  FROM emp e
```

if the health is `NOT-NULL` then second argument will return, otherwise the third argument will return. Btw, using an `ORDER BY` clause will be redundant.

Answer (score 1):

From Oracle 12, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` to find the employees who were sick, got well and then got sick again:

```sql
SELECT emp_id
FROM   emp
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
  PARTITION BY emp_id
  ORDER     BY modification_date
  PATTERN (sick well+ sick)
  DEFINE
    sick AS health IS NOT NULL
    well AS health IS NULL
);
```